# Python Requests: submit JSON in non utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, json, character-encoding, python-requests

I must submit data to a web service which uses a MySQL server configured with latin-1 as the tables collation.  This web service receives a JSON payload and stores some data in the database. UTF-8 is the correct encoding of JSON data for transport, but the web service does not correctly encodes it to latin-1 to save in the database.

So when a submit a JSON like {'Key': 'ç'}, the web service stores it in the incorrect encoding and displays to me in a web page as

```
"The value of Key is 'Ã§'"
```

I'm searching for a workaround.

My client is in Python 3.5 and I'm using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library, which uses urllib3 as plumbing. When I submit a dict to Requests, it uses the `json` lib to convert it to a string type, and urllib3 submits it as a *bytes* to send the request through the network.

Can I make Requests submit my JSON object string with a latin-1 encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, you can manually send json data:

```
a = {'Key': 'ç'}
data = json.dumps(a).encode("latin-1")
requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Then the content you send is a binary string encoded with `latin-1`. Then you can decode it from the server side:

```
res.body.decode("latin-1")
```

Comment: I've deleted other comments here. But I believe that writing data = json.dumps(api_json, ensure_ascii=False); requests.post(url, data=data,headers={"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=latin-1"}) will make it work

Comment: It seems you do not have control on server side? So you have to pass a json type body with latin-1 encoding?

Comment: Sure, this is the problem. I do not control the server and must workaround their bug. Your tip was excellent, way simpler than the paths I were following.